# Linux NFS Share - All files read-only, when mounting in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, nfs, chmod

I have a Raspberry Pi with Raspberry Pi OS (ex Raspbian).

I wanted to share my home folder (/home/pi) with NFS.
I'd like to access it also from my Windows 10 PC, reading and writing files as I was the "pi" user.

I launched the following commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
$ id pi
uid=1000(pi) gid=1000(pi)
$ sudo nano /etc/exports
```

I added this line:

```
/home/pi        *(rw,all_squash,insecure,async,no_subtree_check,anonuid=1000,anongid=1000)
```

And then:

```
$ sudo exportfs -ra
```

After installing the Windows NFS Client component, I was able to connect my RPi home folder as a network drive.
I can create files. However, I cannot edit files.

E.g.:
I created a test file under windows.
I create a test file under linux.

```
pi@sigipi:~ $ echo hello > test_pi.txt
pi@sigipi:~ $ ls -l test_*
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 6 apr 19 23:29 test_pi.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 0 apr 19 23:29 test_windows.txt
```

Both files are now read only from Windows.
I cannot edit them.
(but I can delete them).

Only way to edit them is launching this:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rw test*
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I upgraded to 21H2 & encountered exactly the same issue. Properly mounted according to [this wonderful guide](https://graspingtech.com/mount-nfs-share-windows-10/). Getting irremovable [write-protection / read-only on all files](https://i.imgur.com/1eyV2c3.png). - I started a bounty to bring this up!

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few more things and it seems, that my issue has been resolved. I changed the UID & GID in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ClientForNFS\CurrentVersion\Default` to my default user of my linux system (`id <user>`). I also had to set these IDs in `/etc/exports`.

Now I can remove the `write-protection / read-only` from files. Folders are still marked as protected, but I can delete/edit/move them.

There is a great blog-post that is very recent & in-depth: https://stealthbits.com/blog/mounting-nfs-exports-unix-server/

Comment: To be more specific, you need to create two DWORD values named `AnonymousUid` and `AnonymousGid` if they don't exist and then reboot.